# How to calculate pries from given kilogram and grams

Tags: php, function, logic

I want to create a function which get me a exact pries of given quantity of items in php

my function is like

```
function priesCal ($kg_prise,$qty)
{
//logic
}
```

in my function i want this type of operation

**if 1 kg prise of rise is 50
Than how much prise of 0.500Kg (500gm) ?????**

in my function implementation,
if i run priesCal(50,0.250)
than i want a result like >> 25

So how can i implement this type of logic in php ??

Comment: You should first decide in which units of weight you will perform the price calculation itself. Otherwise, the price calculation itself is: `[quantity * price]`. The example you gived when you call:
`priesCal(50, 0,250)` never returns 25, according to the valid rules of mathematics it returns: 12.5.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the logic will be, quantity*price_per_kg
also, the example you gave will not return 25 as you have passed for 250 grams which is a quarter of 1 kg.

```
function priesCal($kg_prise, $qty) {
    echo $kg_prise * $qty;
}

priesCal(50, 0.250);
```